# How to write a DataFrame to textfile with headers

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a `DataFrame - pd` (as below) which I want to write to a text file, I am successfully able to write it to a csv with `pd.to_csv()` command, but while I write it to a text file I get the data without any headers or index. How can I include the headers and indexes ?

```
 NIST       CG100       CG050  FactoryCal  HMFW (nm)     Sigma   WCalDer
0   605.613  826.487904  826.373969  826.058347   1.425848  1.120941  1.851244
1   587.092  790.587148  790.580384  790.194184   1.376891  1.202015  2.055721
2   690.468  953.660187  953.438435  952.582371   1.874943  0.968623  1.216525
3   681.311  942.452371  942.143394  941.144706   1.630595  0.877735  1.267568
4   431.958  214.029705  214.030983  214.347893   0.711980  2.019422  6.679031
5   665.223  921.620793  921.463130  919.973594   2.804547  1.626438  1.365617
6   450.235  325.734244  325.722302  325.772933   0.738286  1.750162  5.582228
7   557.029  722.478884  722.471888  722.337452   1.491010  1.561811  2.466618
8   427.397  183.088318  183.032558  178.288276   0.752349  2.237605  7.003544
9   669.923  928.331440  928.155865  926.308634   3.186223  1.807440  1.335801
10  645.629  893.315870  893.430749  892.083966   1.174274  0.748784  1.501554
```

Command used to write to text file.

> np.savetxt(os.path.join(new_directory, base_filename2), pd, fmt='%d')

Comment: I don't understand the default params for header and index are `True` for `to_csv`, what version pandas are you using?

Comment: pd.__version__
'0.16.2'

Comment: @EdChum yes the default for header and index are true for to_csv. I have successfully done that to csv file, any method to do the same to a txt file ?

Comment: I don't believe `np.savetxt` supports this

Comment: Pandas wraps around numpy to add things like headers and indices. If you use a numpy function (like `savetxt`), the result isn't going to have those things. If you just want a file with space separators instead of commas, you can use `df.to_csv(fname, sep=' ')`.